# How to use spread operator on object create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new with react-redux concept and I tried to use spread operator. Below is my code:

This is my store(createStore.js):

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

with my reducers using redux combineReducers(only one reducers for now):

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import roleCategory from './roleCategory';

//list of import reducers
export default combineReducers({
  roleCategory
});
```

and my roleCategory reducers is:

```
import { CHANGE_ROLE } from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function reducer(state = 'teacher', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_ROLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        roleCategory : 'student'
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And I have a function to help me dispatch:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';

export function changeRole() {
  return {
    type: types.CHANGE_ROLE
  }
}
```

the way I dispatch is :

`store.dispatch(actions.changeRole());`

my terminal did not give any error, but when I dispatch the action, it give me a white page with some error message in the console.

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
in div (at OptionMenu.jsx:19)
in OptionMenu (created by Connect(OptionMenu))
in Connect(OptionMenu) (at Main.jsx:14)
in div (at Main.jsx:13)
in div (at Main.jsx:11)
in Main (at Root.jsx:13)
in div (at Root.jsx:11)
in Root (at index.js:12)
in Provider (at index.js:11)
at invariant (invariant.js:42)
at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:6748)
at updateSlot (react-dom.development.js:7092)
at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:7239)
at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:7651)
at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:7764)
at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:7747)
at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:7998)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8229)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10288)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:542)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:581)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:438)
at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:10366)
at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:11014)
at performWork (react-dom.development.js:10967)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:11086)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2330)
at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:3421)
invariant @ invariant.js:42
throwOnInvalidObjectType @ react-dom.development.js:6748
updateSlot @ react-dom.development.js:7092
reconcileChildrenArray @ react-dom.development.js:7239
reconcileChildFibers @ react-dom.development.js:7651
reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime @ react-dom.development.js:7764
reconcileChildren @ react-dom.development.js:7747
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js:7998
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:8229
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:10224
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:10288
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:10366
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:11014
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:10967
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11086
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2330
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:3421
index.js:2177 The above error occurred in the <div> component:
in div (at OptionMenu.jsx:19)
in OptionMenu (created by Connect(OptionMenu))
in Connect(OptionMenu) (at Main.jsx:14)
in div (at Main.jsx:13)
in div (at Main.jsx:11)
in Main (at Root.jsx:13)
in div (at Root.jsx:11)
in Root (at index.js:12)
in Provider (at index.js:11)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2177
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:9747
captureError @ react-dom.development.js:10540
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:10391
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:11014
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:10967
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11086
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2330
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:3421
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
in div (at OptionMenu.jsx:19)
in OptionMenu (created by Connect(OptionMenu))
in Connect(OptionMenu) (at Main.jsx:14)
in div (at Main.jsx:13)
in div (at Main.jsx:11)
in Main (at Root.jsx:13)
in div (at Root.jsx:11)
in Root (at index.js:12)
in Provider (at index.js:11)
at invariant (invariant.js:42)
at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:6748)
at updateSlot (react-dom.development.js:7092)
at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:7239)
at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:7651)
at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:7764)
at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:7747)
at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:7998)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8229)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:10288)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:542)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:581)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:438)
at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:10366)
at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:11014)
at performWork (react-dom.development.js:10967)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:11086)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2330)
at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:3421)
```

My Option Menu Code (sorry a bit messy):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import store from '../createStore';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../css/OptionMenu.css';
import * as actions from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  roleCategory: state.roleCategory
});

function changeRoleTo(role) {
  store.dispatch(actions.changeRole(role));
}

function handleClick(e) {
  const target = e.target.innerText;
  if (target === 'teacher') {
    changeRoleTo('teacher');
  } else if (target === 'student') {
    changeRoleTo('student');
  }
}

class OptionMenu extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div className="left-menu" onClick={handleClick}>
          {
            this.props.roleCategory === 'teacher' ? 
            <ul><li className="role">Teacher</li><li>Student</li></ul>:
            <ul><li>Teacher</li><li className="role">Student</li></ul>
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, () => ({}) )(OptionMenu);
```

Comment: Please, show your `OptionMenu` component

Comment: The code you show is not the one causing the error. You need to show the UI component you use.

Comment: The above comments are right. Your error comes from your React component render function and you are just showing your Redux code.

Comment: wait, I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error stack, I think problem might be in your container component.

Comment: Please, post this as a comment instead of an answer

Comment: I did try but don't have enough reputation points to post a comment. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, looks like the error comes from the state of roleCategory student.

Let me explain what is my mistake (if you are already familiar with redux, you might think it is a stupid mistake):

I used combineReducers functions from redux module. combineReducers will separate the state according to every reducers (correct me if I am wrong). So if you have 2 reducers, let's say A and B. your state tree will be an object consist of :

```
{
    A : <state-A>,
    B : <state-B>
}
```

and this state cannot interfere each other (from what I observer). That is why I got errors because I put my B state to be like

```
{
    B : {
            B: <state-of-my-B>
        }  
}
```

above code happen at my roleCategory reducer when I return the new state.